# What wiki engine does FogBugz use?

Tags: fogbugz

What wiki engine does FogBugz use?

Comment: You will get better answers at fogbugz.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/blog/post/The-New-FogBugz-8-Wiki-Editor.aspx